# How to add the total value of a variable within a while a loop

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable that computes a new value each time the loop is ran. How would I add all the values that were computed together?

Comment: Keep a variable with a running total?  Put all the values into a list and get its `sum()`?  Can you show an example or better describe the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi W. Tidwell, and welcome to the site.  The Python docs have a pretty good tutorial that might help you, especially the `list` and `for Statements` sections. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, use a variable outside the scope of your loop. This means (as a basic example)

```
# var outside loop
a = 0

for i in range(0,9):
    # b just known inside the loop
    b = i+i
    a = a + b

print(a)
```